# Navigation Bar in UITableViewController overlaps with status bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, overlap

in my UITableViewControllers I have added navigation bars but the problem is that the Title of the navigation bar intersects with the status bar. Normally I would do "positionForBar" and return UIBarPositioningTopAttached but that only works with UIViewControllers. Thus, I used the "prefersStatusBarHidden" method an return YES. Obviously, this bears a cost to the user since they can't view the time and battery life while they're on those screens while using the app. So is there a way to keep the title navigation bar and the status bar from not overlapping, kinda like in iOS 6?

Here's what i'm talking about:
[image]

it doesn't look very clean and i'm trying to fix it

Comment: not sure why `positionForBar` doesn't work: `UITableViewController` inherits `UIViewController`

Comment: I think it's because I can't move the Navigation Bar like I can in a view controller due to the conflicting UITableView

Comment: you can move tableView as well, can't you?

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard click on your UITableViewController then simply click on edit -> embed -> navigation controller. You don't need to use it to navigate anywhere but it will setup your title bar correctly for you.

Comment: how do I transfer my title bar correctly over? Also, I have it already embedded in a tab bar controller?

Comment: Remove your title bar. You don't need it. It's OK it can be embedded in both.

Comment: What do you mean I don't need it? I just gave one example, but I have other scenes like this that have UIBarButtonItems.

Comment: Yes! Just do the same with them. Basically a NavigationController includes a titlebar where you can put UIBarButtons but also extra space for the status bar and a whole lot of other things to facilite navigation. If there is only one screen per tab then it will not navigate anywhere but you will get all the other benefits of apple formatting done for you. The alternative is to spend a whole lot of time formatting a titlebar yourself (not worth the effort).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. this fixed it: 
credit to: malcolmhall

Its just pushing the nav down but works

```
// in the .h
@property (strong) UINavigationBar* navigationBar;

//in the .m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
self.navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:_navigationBar];
[self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
}

-(void)layoutNavigationBar{
    self.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.topLayoutGuide.length + 44);
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //no need to call super
    [self layoutNavigationBar];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self layoutNavigationBar];
}
```

Comment: This is good if you dont want to embed in a navigation controller